# JSON Response with HTML Content

Tags: javascript, json

I am consulting an API which returns a JSON object and one of the values is badly formatted. It contains \r and \n, when I try to JSON.parse it, it gives me an error. I have tried turning it into a string with JSON.stringify and replace the \r and \n but no luck, it does remove the characters but when i try to parse it again it does not work.

Response

```
            {
            "seller_store_name": "test",
            "seller_store_description": "<blockquote>
<p>ewffwewef</p>
<p>wefwef</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>fewfewf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>efwfewf</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</blockquote>",
            "seller_profile_picture":"",
            "seller_profile_picture_default": "https://test.com/",
            "seller_banner": "",
            "seller_banner_default": "https://test.com/"
        }
```

Attempt 1, turn to string and remove the \r and \n characters

```
sellerData = JSON.stringify(e);

"            {\n            \"seller_store_name\": \"test\",\n            \"seller_store_description\": \"<blockquote>\r\n<p>ewffwewef</p>\r\n<p>wefwef</p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<table>\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n<td>fewfewf</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n<td>&nbsp;</td>\r\n<td>efwfewf</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</tbody>\r\n</table>\r\n</blockquote>\",\n            \"seller_profile_picture\":\"\",\n            \"seller_profile_picture_default\": \"https://test.com\",\n            \"seller_banner\": \"\",\n            \"seller_banner_default\": \"https://test.com\"\n        }\n    "

sellerData = sellerData.replace(/\\r/g,"").replace(/\\n/g,"");
sellerData = JSON.parse(sellerData);
```

This successfully removes the characters but when i try to parse the data again, it does not turn into an object, it stays as a string.

Attempt 2, basic parsing
When i try to parse it, it gives me an error

```
sellerData = JSON.parse(String(e));

Unexpected token in JSON at position 126
```

Any help would be appreciated. Unfortunately, i cannot modify the response from the API.

Comment: It may be proper JSON, have you tried without parsing it?

Comment: if it can be stringified in attempt 1, why not just use `e. seller_store_description ` directly ?

Comment: @djcaesar9114 when i try to do e.seller_store_name, it says it is undefined. I first need to do JSON.parse(String(e)). So this works when the attribute seller_store_description only returns one line, but when it has the format shown in the question, it breaks and shows Unexpected token  in JSON at position 126

Comment: @Littlee if i do console.log(sellerData.seller_store_name) after the stringify, it shows me undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sellerData = sellerData.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "");
```

I think this because of \r\n, so just remove this should be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I tried the following: 
sellerData = JSON.stringify(e);
sellerData = sellerData.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "");
console.log(sellerData);

and it printed out the string with the \n and \r. But as mentioned before, i have managed to remove the \r\n and then tried to parse, but it did not turn into an object.

Comment: I copy your code to test but I need to use this code:  <br />

`sellerData = sellerData.replace(/\r\n/g, "");`